# How to solve this string algorithm?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

So here is the challenge:

I need to update the strings of a specific column in my table following the pattern as the examples below:

- Example 1:
  From: texttext/21/812/21a
  To: texttext-21a81221
- Example 2:
  From: texttext/6/163/38a
  To: texttext-38a1636

"texttext" lenght may vary and may contain slashes (/) as well.

Also, the block 2 and block 3 of numbers can’t have 2 digits.

So,

- texttext/53/7a/a2

  must turn into:

  texttext-0a207a53

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I appreciate your efforts to help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried yourself and the results you are getting. I would do research on `SUBSTRING()`, `CHARINDEX()`, and `REPLACE()` sql functions.

Comment: I really liked this question until I read the line `"texttext" lenght may vary and may contain slashes (/) as well.` ... you absolutely should give us a fixed structure if you have any hope of getting a meaningful query here.  We need to know how many slashes there will be.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean of `block 2 and block 3 of numbers can’t have 2 digits`
Anyway below should give you idea

```
WITH data AS
(
    select Value, REVERSE(Value) AS ReverseValue from (values
        ('texttext/21/812/21a'), ('texttext/6/163/38a'), ('texttext/53/7a/a2'), ('text/t/e/xt/53/7a/a2')
    )t(Value)
), split AS
(
    select 
        Value, ReverseValue, 
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, 1, P1.Pos - 1)) AS Forth,
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, P1.Pos + 1, P2.Pos - P1.Pos - 1)) AS Third,
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1)) AS Second,
        reverse(substring(ReverseValue, p3.Pos + 1, len(ReverseValue))) AS First
    from data       
        cross apply (select (charindex('/', ReverseValue))) as P1(Pos)
        cross apply (select (charindex('/', ReverseValue, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
        cross apply (select (charindex('/', ReverseValue, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
)
select Value, First + '-' + Forth + Third + Second AS NewValue from split
```

Comment: Looks nice Eric. Now, how can I run this from a table?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the value by my select but it's not working.
`select Value, REVERSE(Value) AS ReverseValue from (select myfield from mytable)t(Value), split AS
(
    select`

Comment: You can replace with this `select myfield AS Value, REVERSE(myfield) AS ReverseValue from mytable`